# How do I go about turning the time into a public int?

Tags: c#, datetime, time, unity-game-engine, int

How do I go about turning the time into a public int, I kind of need to convert the TimeSpan difference into seconds and then save it as a  public int.

As in 4 hours , 22 min , 34 seconds  into 15754.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System;

    public class Timeload : MonoBehaviour {

         DateTime  currentDate;
         DateTime  oldDate;


    void Start()
        {
            //Store the current time when it starts
            currentDate = System.DateTime.Now;

            //Grab the old time from the player prefs as a long
            long temp = Convert.ToInt64(PlayerPrefs.GetString("sysString"));

            //Convert the old time from binary to a DataTime variable
            DateTime oldDate = DateTime.FromBinary(temp);
            print("oldDate: " + oldDate);

            //Use the Subtract method and store the result as a timespan variable
            TimeSpan difference = currentDate.Subtract(oldDate);
            print("Difference: " + difference);


    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        //Savee the current system time as a string in the player prefs class
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("sysString", System.DateTime.Now.ToBinary().ToString());

        print("Saving this date to prefs: " + System.DateTime.Now);
    }




    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with just saving it as a datetime?

Comment: I kind of want to use it to multiply with other integers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TotalSeconds property:

```
//Use the Subtract method and store the result as a timespan variable
            TimeSpan difference = currentDate.Subtract(oldDate);
            print("Difference: " + difference.TotalSeconds);
```

Comment: .TotalSeconds is perfect. Now all I need to figure out is how to set the difference . Totalseconds to an integer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved! Thank you everyone!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class Timeload : MonoBehaviour {

DateTime  currentDate;
DateTime  oldDate;

public double timex;

void Start()
{
    //Store the current time when it starts
    currentDate = System.DateTime.Now;

    //Grab the old time from the playerprefs as a long
    long temp = Convert.ToInt64(PlayerPrefs.GetString("sysString"));

    //Convert the old time from binary to a DataTime variable
    DateTime oldDate = DateTime.FromBinary(temp);
    print("oldDate: " + oldDate);

    //Use the Subtract method and store the result as a timespan variable
    TimeSpan difference = currentDate.Subtract(oldDate);
    print("Difference: " + difference.TotalSeconds);

    timex = timex + difference.TotalSeconds;
}

void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    //Save the current system time as a string in the playerprefs class
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("sysString", System.DateTime.Now.ToBinary().ToString());

    print("Saving this date to prefs: " + System.DateTime.Now);
}   
}
```